# Smallest power of line bundle on curve which has a section

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Fix a divisor $D$ of positive degree on an smooth projective algebraic curve, and let $d$ be the smallest positive integer such that $L(dD) \neq 0$. Is there a name for this integer $d$?